# WPF Textbox Scroll Thumb not Visible When Height is Small

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scrollbar

I have a textbox with a height of 80 (I stripped out all the styling).  When there is a vertical scrollbar, I can't see the scroll thumb.  If I increase the height to 500, then I can see the scroll thumb.

[image]

Here is my code for the textbox:

```
<TextBox  Height="80" Text="{Binding ActionComments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="8,1,8,8" Padding="4,0,4,4">

</TextBox>
```

How can I get the scroll thumb to show up in the textbox when the height is 80?

Comment: cannot reproduce. can use use `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` instead of `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`?

Comment: Textbox without custom styles works as expected. Please provide some sample app how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yes, may be something with your styles?

Answer (score 0):

It's working completely fine for me. Maybe you need to add more text into the `TextBox`.

Like Zam said, you can also put `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` then it will always be shown.